# сериализация С# BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, файлы, сериализация

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть класс `User`. В нем есть метод `SaveUser`, который записывает в файл только 1 запись. Есть метод `LoadUsers`, который возвращается список всех записанных в файл пользователей. Ошибка происходит в строчке с комментарием. Он не может конвертировать User в User[]. Как решить эту проблему без переписывания метода `SaveUser`?

```
class User 
{      
    private string name;
    private string password;
    private string key;
    private static string fileName = @"Data\users.dat";
public void SaveUser()
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        // получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, this);
        }
    }
 public static List<User> LoadUsers()
    {
        List<User> listUser = new List<User>();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        //десериализация из файла people.dat
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fs == null)
                return listUser;
            else
            {
                User[] deserilizeUsers = (User[])formatter.Deserialize(fs);// ошибка, нельзя преобразовать User в User[]
                foreach (User user in deserilizeUsers)
                {
                    listUser.Add(user);
                }
            }

         }
         return listUser;
     }
}
```

Comment: Если юзеры записывались в файл по-одному - то и читать их нужно по-одному! В цикле, пока файл не закончится.

Comment: Но лучше откройте для себя SQLite или хотя бы XML-сериализацию. С бинарной сериализацией еще наплачетесь.

Comment: файл не должен быть понятен при открытии редактором. бинарник подходит лучше всего

Comment: Если вы думаете, что для бинарно сериализованных данных не существует редакторов - вы ошибаетесь. Лучше уж шифровать файл чем полагаться на непонятность формата. Но имейте в виду, что шифрование тоже вскрывается специалистом.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov  разве при запуске не будет полностью доступно в открытом виде всё содержимое SQLite ?

Comment: ребят, а можно по делу? файл я шифрую, все нормально, но xml сериализация мне не подойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже сказано в комментарии, десериализовать записи нужно по одной, в цикле. Примерно, так:

```
List<User> listUser = new List<User>();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
    {
        var user = (User)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        listUser.Add(user);
    }
}

return listUser;
```

Конечно, нужно добавить обработку исключений.